# Navigation menu not working properly

Tags: jquery, html, css

I would like to create a navigation menu..

I use jquery for this...

```
   $('.about').on('mouseenter', function(){
        $(this).css({'background':'#144f19'});
        $('.submenu_about').css({'display':'block', 'position':'absolute'});
        $('.items_list').on('mouseout', function(){
            $('.submenu_about').css({'display':'none', 'opacity':'0px'});
            $('.about').css({'background':'none'});
        })
   });
```

But not working properly. Can anybody help me? Thanks in advance.

Comment: how is it not working? if you want us to help when you aren't specific then please set an example up on jsfiddle

Comment: it seems to me what you are doing with jquery can be done using css only

Comment: how it can possible using css only? can you give me the sample code?

Comment: keep the `$('.items_list').on('mouseout', function(){...})` outside of `$('.about').on('mouseenter', function(){...});`

Comment: oh sorry not all of it, but definitely some of it can be done in css

Comment: What isn't working?  How are you expecting it to work?  Here's a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gromer/qNZJn/1/) with some of that in it, but really, not sure what you want to happen.

Comment: @Sheikh Heera i put that outside but not working yet...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be not an answer (you didn't provide enough information to understand the question) but you have right now

```
$('.about').on('mouseenter', function(){
    //...
    $('.items_list').on('mouseout', function(){
        //...
    });
});
```

but it should be

```
​$(function(){
    $('.about').on('mouseenter', function(){
        //...
    });

    $('.items_list').on('mouseout', function(){
        //...
    });
});
```

**Update**:[**May be you want this**](http://jsfiddle.net/3ZSsv/6/).

Answer (score 1):

Here is what you can do, without including jQuery at all.

http://jsfiddle.net/qsENf/1/

I have only included the css for the 'About' section, but the code can be changed easily to handle any of the items. I don't know if this is what you want but it should be close. If you want to use jQuery then you can define the css classes and use jQuery to add them instead of changing the css for all the elements.

Here is the css:

```
.submenu_about {
    display: none;
}

.about {
    background:transparent;
}
.about:hover {
    background:#144f19;
}

.about:hover .submenu_about {
   display: block;
}
```

and the html:

```
<div class="navigation_bar">
  <ul class="menu_list">
    <li class="a_menu_item about">
      About Us
      <div class="submenu_about">
        <ul class="items_list" style="list-style:none">
          <li class="a_sub_menu_item"><a href="#">News and Events</a></li>
          <li class="a_sub_menu_item"><a href="">Financial Assistance</a></li>
          <li class="a_sub_menu_item"><a href="">Who We See</a></li>
          <li class="a_sub_menu_item"><a href="">Insurance Information</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>

    </li>
    <li class="a_menu_item theater">Theater</li>
    <li class="a_menu_item leader">Leadership Team</li>
    <li class="a_menu_item career">Careers</li>
    <li class="a_menu_item contact">Contact Us</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

jQuery isn't necessary for this. If your subnav is not inside of the main nav then jQuery would be useful for toggling its visibility.